# Adding lines to allready exisiting file

Tags: optimization, julia, writetofile, ipopt

I am currently working on an optimization problem where I want to add some information from each IPOPT iteration to a file by using a callback function. I am able to collect the information I need but when I try to add it to the file it only adds a few weird iterations. This is what I am doing (simplified)

I have an outer iteration loop (k) and an inner (the IPOPT iterations)

```
thefile = "output.txt".      # Create a new file 
f = open(thefile, "w").      # The header to my new file 
@printf(f,"%-10s %-10s %-10s\n ", "outer", "inner", "objval" )

k = 0
while k <= 100 
      iter = []
      objValVector = []

      function my_callback( alg_mod::Cint,
        iter_count::Cint,
        obj_value::Float64,
        inf_pr::Float64,
        inf_du::Float64,
        mu::Float64,
        d_norm::Float64,
        regularization_size::Float64,
        alpha_du::Float64,
        alpha_pr::Float64,
        ls_trials::Cint)                # Using the call back function to get the obj.val
         append!(objValvector, obj_value)
         append!(iter, iter_count)
         return true
      end 
 MOI.set(model, Ipopt.CallbackFunction(), my_callback)
 optimize!(model); 

 f = open(thefile, "a");         # Open the file in append "mode" to add to the existing file
 for i in 1:length(iter)
     @printf(f, "%-10s %-10s %-10s\n", 
            k, iter[i], objValvector[i])
 end

Do something...
k += 1; 


end
```

I really don't understand why this should not work?
The file looks like this:
[image: The file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open the same file twice (which should not happen).
And you do not `flush` the buffer.
Hence you are seeing a mix of what made to the disk and what did not make to the disk.

`close(f)` in the fourth line and at the end of the code. Or just open it once. Depending on your other code and scenario you might want to `flush(f)` as well.